# Salesforce EventBrite Integration (EventBrite event search request)

Tags: api, salesforce, apex, eventbrite

I am working on an integration project between [Salesforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salesforce) and [Eventbrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventbrite). I have already done the authentication and retrieve user's events and its attendees.

Since it always bringing all the event data and all the attendee data to the Salesforce, I needed to reduce the payload by taking only the modified data since the last request.

I was able to get the attendees for a given event. However, when I search the events as in the Eventbrite [API documentation](https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api#/reference/event-search) it works fine in the [PostMan client](https://www.getpostman.com/).

[image]

However, when I use the [Salesforce Apex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salesforce#Salesforce_Platform) code to do the same request it gives me "301 Moved Permanently" error. After searching while I realized that people are adding "/" to the start of the query parameter. So I used the "/" to in attendee filtering request and it worked, but this time it as ignored the filters in the query parameters. See the code and the result in the picture (note the highlighted backslash).

[image]

How can I filter the result using Apex code?